# Can someone explain this "endian-ness" function for me?

Tags: c++, endianness

Write a program to determine whether a computer is big-endian or little-endian.

```
bool endianness() {
     int i = 1;
     char *ptr;
     ptr  = (char*) &i;
     return (*ptr);
}
```

So I have the above function. I don't really get it. ptr = (char*) &i, which I think means a pointer to a character at address of where i is sitting, so if an int is 4 bytes, say ABCD, are we talking about A or D when you call char* on that? and why?

Would some one please explain this in more detail? Thanks.

So specifically, ptr  = (char*) &i; when you cast it to char*, what part of &i do I get?

Comment: it would be more understandable if you named the function `littleEndian()` since it returns true if the architecture is little endian. `endianness() == true` is not very informative.

Comment: It could be written much more concisely: `bool little_endian (void) { static const int i = 1; return reinterpret_cast<const char&>(i) == 1; }`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have a little-endian architecture, `i` will look like this in memory (in hex):

```
01 00 00 00
^
```

If you have a big-endian architecture, `i` will look like this in memory (in hex):

```
00 00 00 01
^
```

The cast to `char*` gives you a pointer to the first byte of the int (to which I have pointed with a `^`), so the value pointed to by the `char*` will be `01` if you are on a little-endian architecture and `00` if you are on a big-endian architecture.

When you return that value, `0` is converted to `false` and `1` is converted to `true`.  So, if you have a little-endian architecture, this function will return `true` and if you have a big-endian architecture, it will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If `ptr` points to byte A or D depends on the endianness of the machine. `ptr` points to that byte of the integer that is at the lowest address (the other bytes would be at `ptr+1`,...).

On a big-endian machine the *most* significant byte of the integer (which is `0x00`) will be stored at this lowest address, so the function will return zero.

On a litte-endian machine it is the opposite, the *least* significant byte of the integer (`0x01`) will be stored at the lowest address, so the function will return one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is using type punning to access an integer as an array of characters. If the machine is big endian, this will be the major byte, and will have a value of zero, but if the machine is little endian, it will be the minor byte, which will have a value of one. (Instead of accessing `i` as a single integer, the same memory is accessed as an array of four chars).

Answer (score 0):

Whether `*((char*)&i)` is byte A or byte D gets to the heart of endianness. On a little endian system, the integer 0x41424344 will be laid out in memory as: 0x44 43 42 41 (least significant byte first; in ASCII, this is "DCBA"). On a big endian system, it will be laid out as: 0x41 42 43 44. A pointer to this integer will hold the address of the first byte. Considering the pointer as an integer pointer, and you get the whole integer. Consider the pointer as a char pointer, and you get the first byte, since that's the size of a char.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let's take a look:

```
bool endianness() {
     int i = 1; //This is 0x1:
     char *ptr;
     ptr  = (char*) &i; //pointer to 0001
     return (*ptr);
}
```

If the machine is Little endian, then data will be in *ptr will be 0000 0001.

If the machine is Big Endian, then data will be inverted, that is, i will be

```
i = 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So *ptr will hold 0x0

Finally, the return *ptr is equivalent to

```
if (*ptr = 0x1 ) //little endian

else //big endian
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume int is 4 bytes (in C it may not be).  This assumption is just to simplify the example...

You can look at each of these 4 bytes individually.

`char` is a byte, so it's looking at the first byte of a 4 byte buffer.

If the first byte is non 0 then that tells you if the lowest bit is contained in the first byte.

I randomly chose the number 42 to avoid confusion of any special meaning in the value 1.

```
int num = 42;
if(*(char *)&num == 42)
{
      printf("\nLittle-Endian\n");
}
else
{
      printf("Big-Endian\n");
}
```

**Breakdown:**

```
int num = 42; 
//memory of the 4 bytes is either: (where each byte is 0 to 255)
//1) 0 0 0 42
//2) 42 0 0 0

char*p = &num;/*Cast the int pointer to a char pointer, pointing to the first byte*/
bool firstByteOf4Is42 = *p == 42;/*Checks to make sure the first byte is 1.*/

//Advance to the 2nd byte
++p;
assert(*p == 0);

//Advance to the 3rd byte
++p;
assert(*p == 0);

//Advance to the 4th byte
++p;
bool lastByteOf4Is42 = *p == 42;
assert(firstByteOf4Is42 == !lastByteOf4Is42);
```

If firstByteOf4Is42 is true you have little-endian. If lastByteOf4Is42 is true then you have big-endian.